# Would 'the dead' be considered an object or person?

Tags: word-choice

Here is the piece of text that I'm trying to figure out:

> Eventually, she stood up with weak legs and trembling arms that held a bundle of unresponding flesh and walked slowly towards the room that would lead her to the basement, the location where they disposed of the dead, who be eventually taken by their relatives and friends to be placed six feet under.

-I don't know whether to put "who" or "which" in "...The location where they disposed of the dead, ???? be eventually taken..."

Please help.

P.s. If you see grammar mistakes in the given text, please tell me. I'm pretty young and nearly have little to no experience in writing, so pardon my lack of knowledge.

Thank you for your time,

Totos Samali

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, *'dead'* are usually referred to as persons. However, '*dead bodies*' are treated as objects. So, in your case it would be better to go with

> who be eventually taken...

Also, you could say *who **are** eventually taken*